# how to get count of menu options ----Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am learning Selenium. i want to get count of menu options of Testing menu..

**Website url:** https://www.guru99.com/

**My Code is:**

```
List<WebElement> Options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='maximenuck2']//li//a[@class='maximenuck']//span"));
System.out.println("Size>>>>>>>"+Options.size());
```

**Console output is:** `Size>>>>>>>0`

Comment: could you please share your HTML page ?

Comment: You need to click on the testing menu first and then need to find the submenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first click on the testing menu and then need to find the Submenu options of the Testing Menu.

**Modified Code:**

```
//To Click on the Testing Menu
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='g-navigation']//ul[@class=' maximenuck']/li//span[text()='Testing']")).click();

List<WebElement> Options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='floatck submenuck118']//ul[@class='maximenuck2']/li"));
System.out.println("Size>>>>>>>"+Options.size());
```

**Output:**

Size>>>>>>>20

**Edit:**

**Clarification:**

In the HTML, there is some extra space is present in the class name [`maximenuck` ].But you have used as [`@class='maximenuck'`] in your xpath and hence it is returning the count as 0.

So, you can modify the xpath as `//ul[@class='maximenuck2']//li//a[contains(@class,'maximenuck')]//span`. (to avoid the extra space issue)

However, xpath `//ul[@class='maximenuck2']//li//a[contains(@class,'maximenuck')]//span`  will find all the submenus from all the menus like (Testing, SAP, Big Data ...).

In order to fetch the testing related submenus, you need to add some other unique reference in your xpath as below

**Xpath 1:** `//div[@class='floatck submenuck118']//ul[@class='maximenuck2']/li`

I have just added some unique identification before the yours Xpath

**Xpath 2** :  `//div[@class='floatck submenuck118']//ul[@class='maximenuck2']//li//a[contains(@class,'maximenuck')]//span`

Comment: It really helped me a lot.. :) 
may i know the reason why does my xpath dint work. its getting highlighted from firebug,then whats d problem with my xpath
List<WebElement> Options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='maximenuck2']//li//a[@class='maximenuck']//span"));

Comment: some extra space is present in the anchor tag's class name and hence it is returning as null. I think, firebug might be eliminated that space . I have edited the answer with some additional details.Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Use `By.cssSelector(".submenuck118 .titreck")` instead